# Browse through a map out of template classes via Iterator

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

i am using c++ and i have the problem that every call of the Method "getItem()" from the following code returns 0 although this is not the integer written in the map and also the map ist not empty. Is there any Problem with using the "typename..." statement as a class attribute?

```
    template <class t>
    class P {
    public:
        P(); 
        int getItem();

    private:
        std::map<int, P<t>* > m;
        typename std::map<int, P<t>* >::iterator it;
        bool visited;
    };

    template <class t>
    P<t>::P() {
      visited=false;
    }

    template <class t>
    int P<t>::getItem()
    {
        if(!visited) 
            it=m.begin();
        int i=it->first;
        it++;
        return i;
    }
```

The methode "getItem()" is only called after there are no more changes to the map. So there shouldn't be a reasons why the iterator is not valid. I am adding items to the map by calling m[i]=p.

Thanks for any help ;)

Comment: That's all? Is `visited` initialized to `false`? How do you add elements to the `map`? Are you certain that the `iterator` remains valid?

Comment: In the constructor of P `visited` is set to `false`. I add elements to the map by calling `m[i]=p` for valid integers, which are never `0` and valid class objects `p`. I call the function after all elements are added to the map so I don't change it while calling the method. Is there any other reason why the iterator could not be valid anymore?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! In mysteries like this, we often find the bug is in the code that you *don't* post, rather than the code you do. (After all, if you knew where the bug was, you wouldn't be here, would you?) Please reduce your original program to the smallest **complete** program that demonstrates the error (often, 20 lines or so). Then copy-paste that **entire** program into the question. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: @Heusi You never set `visited` to true, the iterator is set to `begin()` in every call of `getItem()`. You could initialize the iterator in constructor and get rid of `visited` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You do not set the "visited" boolean, so if you run through a loop which makes "getItem", you always reinitialize the iterator "it".

Comment: Sorry i didn't mentioned it but there is a constructor in which `visited` is set. I will edit my post ;)

Comment: I think the default value for a boolean is "false". So you never set
it to true, even when you have already visited your data structure.

So each call to getItem will return the first index. But, are you sure you never write m[0] somewhere? Can you add some code which shows the use of this class?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't set `visited` to `true` at any point, you *always* return the integer of the first item in the `map` which is presumably `0`. You probably meant something like:

```
if(!visited)
{
    visited = true;
    it=m.begin();
}
```